# Why does this Django form complain "this field is required" for an image field?

Tags: python, django, image, forms

Using 'Photologue', I can upload images as part of a form no problem. In the test plans however, I am having trouble getting an image to validate.

In tests.py:

```
data_photo = {'competition': self.newcomp,  
                  'title': 'Rabbit',
                  'image': open('photocompetitions/static/img/body_bg.jpg'),
                  'flickr_id': '425258',
                  'description': 'A picture of a rabbit',
                  'location': 'POINT (5000 5000)',
                  'location_description': 'Just some random place',
                  'copyright': 'Copyright 2011'}
photoform = PhotoForm(data_photo)
```

Everything works fine except the 'image' field which fails as a 'This field is required.' message so I am assuming that it is not being received despite the open() command. the 'image' field is the photologue's ImageModel model and appears on the site as a standard upload form.

Comment: Why image field is a model but not *ImageField*? Are you sure that your form handles constructor with parameter 'data_photo'? Why do you try to open the file on a server 'body_dg.jpg'?

Comment: What do you mean? the 'image' field in this form example above is a part of ImageModel in the photologue app which is an ImageField.

Answer (score 6):

You have to pass an image not in `data`, but in the `files` parameter of the form.

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

img = open('photocompetitions/static/img/body_bg.jpg')
uploaded = SimpleUploadedFile(img.name, img.read())
photoform = PhotoForm(data_photo, files={'image': uploaded})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use 'rb' options for open file:

```
'image': open('photocompetitions/static/img/body_bg.jpg', 'rb')
```

Comment: this does not work in Django 1.6.X, what version did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a bmp rather than a jpg?

I remember that there is an issue with the way PIL is loaded by the django test framework.

the jpg format may not be enabled correctly in this case but bmp should be ok.

I hope it helps